# Take photo and record video of real-time face detection preview

Tags: android, opencv, face-detection, javacv

I have used JavaCv (and opencv too) to implement live face detection preview on Android. I work ok. Now I want to take a picture or record a video from live preview which have face detection (I mean when I take a picture, this picture will have a person and a rectangle around his/her face). I have researched a lot but get no result. Can anyone help me please !!!

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the `imwrite()` method.

Since your question isn't clear on the use-case, I'll give a generic algorithm, as shown:

`imwrite`  writes a specified Mat object to a file and it accepts 2 arguments - fileName and Mat object, for example - `imwrite('output.jpg',img);`

Here's the logic you can follow:

> - Receive input frame (`Mat input` from video and run face detection using your existing method.
>
> Draw a rectangle on an output image (`Mat output`).
>
> Use imwrite as - `imwrite('face.jpg',output)`

In case you want to record all the frames with a face in them, replace 'face.jpg' with a string variable that is updated with each loop iteration and run imwrite in a loop

If you wish to record a video. Have a look at VideoWriter() class